# How to setup domain & its sub domain to different Firebase hosting projects

Tags: firebase, subdomain, firebase-hosting

Suppose my domain is `mydomain.com`, and subdomain `subdomain.mydomain.com`. I got it from Godaddy.

**What I want**

I want to run different websites on each.

`mydomain.com` -> Website 1

`subdomain.mydomain.com` -> Website 2

**How I setup so far**

`Website 1` is hosted on `Firebase project 1` and accessible via default URL `firebase-projectid.firebaseapp.com`.

`Website 2` is hosted on `Firebase project 2` and accessible via default URL.

Both Firebase projects are on same Google account.

**What I have done successfully so far**

I started with `mydomain.com` -> Website 1

Verified domain by adding TXT record provided by `Firebase project 1`.

Added couple of A records to point domain to `Firebase project 1` hosting.

So far so good, and `mydomain.com` is working fine.

**What is not working**

Now I want to host `subdomain.mydomain.com` -> Website 2 with `Firebase project 2`.

I started with custom subdomain, added `subdomain.mydomain.com`. Firebase had already verified domain and directly provided me ip address for A records. I added both A records on my domain registrar.

As far as I understand, these are only steps needed. But `subdomain.mydomain.com` is not working and Firebase still shows status of subdomain as `Needs Setup`.

**Observations**

Two things I observed seems strange to me.

1. IP address provided by Firebase for both projects `mydomain.com` and `subdomain.mydomain.com` are same. Not sure if this is normal or not.
2. `subdomain.mydomain.com` with A records, is not propagating when checked on `https://dnschecker.org/`. However, if subdomain is added via Godaddy Forwarding option, then it start propagating in few minutes.

**Questions**

1. BTW, is it really possible to host domain and its subdomain on Firebase running different websites?
2. If yes, then is there any other step which I am missing?
3. Any idea why `subdomain.mydomain.com` is not propagating. I checked just after 10 mins. May be I need to wait longer?
4. Anything wrong I am doing to setup subdomain.

I tried exploring other threads but couldn't understand what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: For Observation #1, yes it is normal.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After scratching my head for few more hours I found issue at Godaddy side. While adding subdomain A record, I was providing host as `subdomain.mydomain.com`, which was wrong.

Instead of `subdomain.mydomain.com` host should have been `subdomain` only. After updating host it started propagating in few seconds, and status on Firebase is `Pending`. After a minute, `subdomain.mydomain.com` is working fine.

Comment: Thanks, I got the same issue, the firebase "mini guide" only shows the full A records, it needs to be updated to include this.

Comment: Ahh ty spent a few hours messing with this. A few minutes after changing it to just the subdomain on Godaddy, its now pending.

Comment: it's been 2 year but neither on GoDaddy nor Firebase i got this step. I waited for 1.5 days and thought to check on stackoverflow and in 5 minutes it worked like charm. Thank you